# Merge sort throwing index out of bounds exception in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement a simple merge sort for even number of elements using the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int arr1[10],int len1,int arr2[10],int len2,int arr3[10],int len3)
{
    int i,j,k;
    while(i<len1&&j<len2&&k<len3)
    {
        if(arr1[i]<arr2[j])
        {
            arr3[k] = arr1[i];
            i++;k++;
        }
        else if(arr1[i]>arr2[j])
        {
            arr3[k] = arr2[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int a[10],int n)
{
    int arr1[10],arr2[10];
    for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = a[i];
    }
    for(int i=(n/2+1);i<n;i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = a[i];
    }
    mergeSort(arr1,n/2);
    mergeSort(arr2,n/2);
    merge(arr1,n/2,arr2,n/2,a,n);
}



int main() {
    int arr[10],n;
    cout << "Enter number of elements\n";
    cin >> n;
    cout<<"Enter elements\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    mergeSort(arr, n);
    cout<<"Sorted array is"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting a `EXC_BAD_ACESS` error on the opening brace of the `mergeSort()` method. I am new to `Xcode` and not sure on how to fix this. How do I fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Assuming n==10, n/2+1 = 6, are you skipping an element?

Comment: You never break out of `mergeSort`, it'll keep calling itself ad infinitum.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with Xcode. It is simply an improper algorithm, the most notable issue pointed out above.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to initialize the int variables i, j, k to 0 (zero) in the function definition for merge(...).

```
void merge(int arr1[10],int len1,int arr2[10],int len2,int arr3[10],int len3)
{
    // int i,j,k;    // Not initialized.
    int i = j = k = 0;
    while(i<len1&&j<len2&&k<len3)
    {
       ...
       ...
}
```

### After Edit:

```
void mergeSort(int a[10],int n)
{
    int arr1[10],arr2[10];
    for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = a[i];
    }
    // Here you are skipping the middle index.
    // Let's say array is of length 10, then arr1 contains elements on index from 0 to 4 (5 elements),
    // whereas arr2 contains elements on index from 6 to 9 (4 elements).
    // 5th index element is missing.

    // for(int i=(n/2+1);i<n;i++)
    for(int i=(n/2);i<n;i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = a[i];
    }
    mergeSort(arr1,n/2);
    mergeSort(arr2,n/2);
    merge(arr1,n/2,arr2,n/2,a,n);
}
```

Hope it helps!